# Linux Directory Size Issue with C

Tags: c, linux

Here is what I need to do:

> Write a C program to calculate the total size of the files in a
>   directory and the sub-directories of the directory. Note that the
>   total size should include the sizes of sub-directories (directories
>   are also files) and size of the top-level directory. If a file is a
>   symbolic link, the symbolic link should not be dereferenced. So the
>   size of the symbolic link is added to the total size, not the size of
>   the file pointed by the link. To facilitate testing, your program
>   should print out ONLY the total size in bytes, i.e., ONE number,
>   nothing else.

Here is what I have:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char* folder =  argv[1]; 
    long length;
    DIR* dir_p;
    struct dirent* dir_element;
    struct stat file_info;

    dir_p = opendir(folder);

    while(dir_element = readdir(dir_p)){

        lstat(dir_element->d_name, &file_info);
        length+=file_info.st_size;
        printf("%s\n" , dir_element->d_name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that I do not get the right number for some reason. I check the output of my program with du -abc "directory_pathname" call in Ubuntu(Linux).

Comment: While you can do this recursively with `opendir`, don't forget to check the man page for `ftw` and `nftw` (same page). Walking an entire directory tree is basically what they do. (though the use of callback functions may be present a bit of a learning curve) (it's just a function pointer to pass to process each file or directory the way you need it done)

Comment: I tried doing what you said and now I am getting segemtation fault and I am not able to post a new question what should I do

Comment: Neil, take a look at the example include in [ftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftw.3.html). It should help you through it.

Comment: Do I need to define X_OPEN_SOURCE

Comment: If you are using `nftw` (yes), man page says `nftw(): _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500`, if you are just using `ftw`, then (no). The man pages, while admittedly cryptic at first, are very concise references to every function in the c library. (and for assembly calling convention use as well). Well worth making friends with them. Let me know if you have more issues.

Answer (score 3):

You never initialize `length`.  Also, you need to actually recurse into directories.  Put the `while` into a function, then call that function for each directory you find (check `man stat` to figure out how to tell if the file is a directory; I forget the exact test off the top of my head but it's a member of `struct stat`).

Comment: can you show me a sample of recurse function relating to this question?

Comment: @NeilShah - Speaking from personal experience, you'll learn way more struggling a bit.  If you can't figure it out, update your question with the new code and updated symptoms.